# The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 8.5.6. A Tomcat 8.0 installation is expected

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, servlets

while trying to deploy my application to Apache using Eclipse, it gives

```
The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 8.5.6.  A Tomcat 8.0 installation is expected.
```

what i did is= Run As--->Run On Server--->Manually define a new server--->click on Apache--->Tomcat v8.0 Server--->next--->Browse the installation directory and select it--->then it gives the above error.

Comment: i don't have "Tomcat V8.5.6 Server" option that is the reason i click "Tomcat V8.0 Server" option

Comment: @SeanF Thanks alot, I gat the correct answer from the link. now my second question is how to delete my question

Comment: No need to close it, as if someone has the same problem as you and searches for the question how you wrote it, they will be directed on to that answer.